Can I easily cherry pick some commit to stash?
I'd like to pick some commit from the history and load its changes to my stash, just to use it freely anywhere. Is it possible?
Edit: thanks for your answers, maybe I'd add that I hoped for some way to do this without interfering with the current code state (what occurs while using reset).

Your question is a bit confusing because: git cherry-pick is already a way to use any commit anywhere freely. No need to go through the stash.

Why not just tag the commit?

@LeGEC - not so much freely, because it adds this commit to my changes history. However yeah, I can just reset it (assuming I have no own uncommitted and unstashed changes).

If I understand correctly: you are after the result of git stash apply, which applies a patch on your files but does not create a commit ? That's git cherry-pick -n or git apply

also: if my last comment is correct, please update your question. The current wording reads "I need to have a commit listed in my stash", your need would rather be "how can I get the changes of another commit on my files, without creating a new commit ?"

I wrote "load its changes", not "load the commit". I think that's clear, isn't it? Also, is it possible to have a commit saved in the stash? I assumed it's not.

Yes, first cherry-pick the commit, then reset the current branch to the previous commit while keeping the cherry-picked changes in the working tree, and then stash them.
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
git reset HEAD^
git stash


Yeah, it should work, however, we need to ensure that we don't have any own uncommitted and unstashed changes. I just hoped that there is some immediate command to do this without interfering with our current code state.

You should consider doing this on a separate working tree if you do not want to mess up with what you have in the current working tree.

It could be done like this:
git checkout the-commit-to-stash
git reset --soft @~
git stash

Another one, but it's the same concept, just different operations to get to the same state
git checkout the-commit-to-stash~ # keep pigtail
git restore --worktree --index --source the-commit-to-stash -- .
git stash


If you want to apply the changes from another commit to your working tree without creating a new commit, git cherry-pick has a -n|--no-commit option:
git cherry-pick -n [other commit]

This will place the changes in the index, and additionally prepare the
text for the next commit (file .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG) with the text of the original cherry-picked commit.
If you have an imperious need to only apply changes on the worktree and not change the index, you should probably go with git apply:
git show [other commit] | git apply -


This is possible, first, create a branch so that you don't accidentially break anything. Use git log to locate the commit hash, copy it. Then use git reset --mixed <hash>. This will put the changes from the commit in your unstaged changes. From here you can use your standard git stash commands.
Recap:

git switch -c <name> to create new branch
git log to get hash
git reset --mixed <hash> to unstage changes
git stash


No need to run git log to get hash, the previous commit is @~ or HEAD^; see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADmaster3em

@phd - Absolutely correct, but only if it was the last commit. Otherwise, if the commit you want is further back in time, then you have to retrieve the hash from somewhere else.
